# Поделитесь вашей функцией отправки подготовленных запросов в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Чтоб подключалась к бд, отправляла подготовленный запрос, сама его фильтровала.

А то сейчас ощущаю как пишу велосвипед.

Я считаю, что для создания подготовленных запросов уходит слишком много телодвижений

```
$sth = $connection->prepare("UPDATE `table` SET `a` = :a WHERE `id` = :id");
$sth->execute(array('a' => 1, 'id' => $id));
```

Сперва нам нужно прописать условные идентификаторы :a :id

Затем каждому идентификатору назначить значение, печатая ' => , все посчитать, проследить нет ли где лишнего, совпадают ли поля со значениями

Почему бы не использовать просто функцию? Мне гугл абсолютно не помог найти готовое. Делаем массив

```
$chto[] = "info1"; $kuda[] = "pole1";
$chto[] = "info2"; $kuda[] = "pole2";
$chto[] = "info3"; $kuda[] = "pole3";
$chto[] = "info4"; $kuda[] = "pole4";
```

Передаем в функцию массив, она сама генерирует что там надо.

Я уверен у кого-то есть эта функция, поделитесь пожалуйста

Comment: почему бы не использовать готовые решения например `RedBeanPHP` или `EloquentORM` ?

Answer (score 0):

> все посчитать, проследить нет ли где лишнего, совпадают ли поля со значениями

Никто не заставляет использовать именованные плейсхолдеры и архаичный синтаксис. Можно использовать позиционные

```
$connection->prepare("UPDATE table SET a = 1 WHERE id = ?")->execute([$id]);
```

Я не вижу, чем этот вариант будет принципиально хуже возни с массивами "$chto" и "$kuda".

С функциями же, которые сами решают "что" и "куда" надо быть осторожными, поскольку они легко могут привести к [SQL инъекции](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/sql_injection_example).
Учитывая, что единственный надежный вариант - это явно перечислить все поля в скрипте, то выигрыша у такой "функции" перед приведенным выше кодом тоже не будет.

Если же хочется непременно использовать функции, то надо использовать проверенный ORM или query builder, но новички обычно их страшно боятся.